# Use Enum in JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, enums

I have enum fields in DB in lowercase and as per Java standard, I have to define them in Uppercase in my spring boot application. If I am using lowercase, enums, I am able to get the results, but trying to convert DB lowercase value to uppercase using Spring attribute converter which is not working. Could someone tell me where I am doing wrong?

AccountLimitType.java

```
public enum AccountLimitType {
    NONE,
    HARD,
    SOFT;
}
```

ConvertToDBAccountLimitType.java

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class ConvertToDBAccountLimitType implements AttributeConverter<AccountLimitType, String>{

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(AccountLimitType attribute) {
        return attribute.toString().toLowerCase();
    }

    @Override
    public AccountLimitType convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return AccountLimitType.valueOf(dbData.toUpperCase());
    }

}
```

Field in Entity class:

```
    @NotNull
    @Convert(converter = ConvertToDBAccountLimitType.class)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="limit_type",columnDefinition = "ENUM('none','hard','soft') default 'none'")
    private AccountLimitType accountLimitType;
```

This is the response I am getting:
[Response in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh452.jpg)

Comment: Why can't you use the uppercase values in the database?

Comment: Same database table is getting used at many places in different projects. So, it's not possible to change enum values in database. Also, I think MYSQL has also naming convention of according to which enum values should be in lowercase.

Comment: do you use hibernate ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try without  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
Also make sure that its calling your converter and don't forget to add a null check there